# Replace text in word

Tags: vb.net

I want to replace text from

Ref No         :

become

Ref No         : xyz1234

My coding as below:

```
Dim oReader As New StreamReader(Frm1.lblFileName.Text)
Dim sLine As String = Nothing
While Not oReader.EndOfStream
    sLine = oReader.ReadLine()
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine)) Then
        If sLine.Contains("Ref No") Then
            sLine.Replace("Ref No", "xyz1234")
        End If
    Else
    End If
End While
oReader.Close()
```

It does not replace the Ref No: with Ref No:xyz1234.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your code at face value, it seems you're missing a couple things. The most obvious is that the output of the Replace() method must be assigned to another string.

So, your line:

```
sLine.Replace("Ref No", "xyz1234")
```

becomes:

```
sLine = sLine.Replace("Ref No", "xyz1234")
```

Also, as @Curt pointed out, your actual substitution, based on your description, would be:

```
sLine = sLine.Replace("Ref No :", "Ref No : xyz1234")
```

I also can't see how you're preserving the changes made in sLine, but I'm going to assume that's because you've simplified your example. Needless to say, you need to be storing the value of sLine somewhere after each iteration of the loop. For example something link this:

```
Dim sLine As String
Dim sText As New Stringbuilder
Dim oReader As New StreamReader(Frm1.lblFileName.Text)
While Not oReader.EndOfStream
  sLine = oReader.ReadLine()
  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine) AndAlso sLine.Contains("Ref No :") Then
    sLine = sLine.Replace("Ref No :", "Ref No : xyz1234")
  End If
  sText.AppendLine(sLine)
End While
oReader.Close()
Frm1.lblFileName.Text = sText.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

Change:

```
   If sLine.Contains("Ref No") Then
      sLine.Replace("Ref No", "xyz1234")
```

to

```
   If sLine.Contains("Ref No") Then
      sLine.Replace("Ref No", "Ref No: xyz1234")
```

Your logic is right, but once you modify the string, you don't do anything with it.   Replace() doesn't modify the string in place, but returns a new string with the string replacement effected.   Since you're not assigning it to anything, or printing it, it's just getting thrown away.   You might want to do something like

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

.. and then

```
   If sLine.Contains("Ref No") Then
      sb.Append(sLine.Replace("Ref No", "xyz1234"))
   else sb.Append(sline)
```

but it would be easier to read the whole file into a string, and do a single Replace on that.

Comment: If you want to modify a Word document, you'll have to do Word automation (or purchase a commercial library that knows how to read and write Word files).   Here's an article that can get you started:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55685/Word-Automation-using-VB-NET-Part-I

Comment: Ya.I get the result by using doc API.Thnx.

Comment: The use of Replace in this example is wrong.  Replace returns a new string with the replacements, it does not modify the existing string.

Comment: I don't understand your comment:  that was precisely the point I had made.   What was wrong with my example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not assuming anything now, but your code doesn't show how and with what you read the DOCX file. 
Assuming it's a DOCX file :) 
In case it is and you don't have a DOCX reader, look at "Open XML Format SDK". 
Next thing is, you have to put the value back in to the variable that holds the string and that you haven't done that and you aren't saving the result back to the DOCX file.

sLine = sLine.Replace("Ref No", "Ref No:xyz1234")
You are just closing the reader after you have read the file and done a replace on the string holding the read text from a filename, this is done in a raw text manner it seems or maybe you haven't shown us the whole code.

Cheers, Mik